# Converting String to Date Format in Python

Tags: python, date

I have the following date I need to convert:

```
Wed, 09 Jul 2014 12:22:17 +0000
```

This is currently stored as a String. I wrote this code to convert it to the date format I want (the String above is passed as an argument to the covertDate function):

```
def convertDate(dictValue):

    date_string = dictValue
    format_string = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
    date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format_string)
    date_correct_form = date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(type(date_correct_form))
    print(date_correct_form)

    return date_correct_form
```

The output is as follows:

```
<class 'str'>
2014-10-30
```

I get the format that I want, but it still isn't recognized as a date.

How can I make it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning `date_correct_form`, which is the result of [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

> **Return a string representing the date**, controlled by an explicit format string.

(emphasis mine)

If you want the datetime object, return `date_object`. If you need both, you can return both:

```
return date_correct_form, date_object
```

You can call it like so:

```
date_string, date_obj = convertDate(dictValue)
```

You now have the already formatted string in `date_string`, and if you still need to do logic against the datetime object, that is in `date_obj`

Comment: Is there any way I can convert date_object to %Y-%m-%d format, and still have it as a datetime type?

Comment: No. A datetime object is not the same thing as a string object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
converted_date = date_converter.string_to_date(date_string, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```